# How to lighten a Windows 11 ISO image?

Tags: windows-11, iso-image

When you download a Windows 11 ISO file, there are plenty versions in the ISO (like Windows 11 Education, Education N, Pro, Pro N, ...).

Is there any way to remove all the other versions in the ISO image file and just keep one (for example "Windows 11 Pro").

[image]

Comment: Possibly, by creating a custom WIM: https://www.uubyte.com/create-custom-windows-11-iso-for-installation.html , That link shows how to use WIM Converter to reduce number of versions in ISO. That said, it's a bit time-consuming, and might not save much space, because different versions of Windows are built on a common frame, with only small changes for each version.

Comment: Each of those will just be subsets of the same image, so if you want the 'top model' there's nothing to lighten.

Comment: "Is there any way to remove all the other versions in the ISO image file and just keep one (for example "Windows 11 Pro")." - There is but it won't reduce the size of the ISO image by any significant amount. What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound - I think we can only assume the OP thinks there are 7 entire installers there, 6 of which are 'wasted space'.

Comment: Is your goal to make as small an installer as possible, or to only have one Windows license type available in the installer? I do not believe that one is necessarily, or strongly, related to the other. Windows license versions use largely the same files, and the different licenses are more about features being enabled or disabled than about one or another set of files. The installer size will not change much simply by "removing" the license types you don't need. Tell us what your primary goal is, and we'll be able to point you in the right direction.